# Understanding Dimension Tables - Best Approach - Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I wanted to know what would be the best approach for creating the dim tables.   Can I maintain it as a single table with all fields and use them as required or create separate dim tables and use them individually.

Can someone please help me out here

PS: I'm a beginner here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating 1 table per dimension is the best practice. In data warehouse concept, you will get 4 types of schema as below-

1. Start Schema
2. Snowflakes Schema
3. Galaxy Schema
4. Combined Schema

People select any of the above based on their Data type/nature, requirement and other parameter. But in all case, there are single table per dimension. This is easy to maintain and give better performance.